# Very slow product deletion in Prestashop 1.6.0.9

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am running Prestashop powered shop. I have about 25000 products. I have problems with deleting product. Whenever I press delete button in backoffice it keeps loading. When I refresh the page the product gets deleted from the products list in the backoffice. I have this problem for both old and new products. Can somebody with experience in Prestashop explain me that?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this [thread](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/290810-very-slow-products-deleting-and-overall-performance/) in Prestashop forum I managed to improve product deletion process. I guess the main reason is MySQL is very slow for delete/update/insert when using InnoDB. So I have dumped my database and changed all occurrences of InnoDB to MyISAM. This helped me to improve the product deletion speed a little bit (5 products per minute).